# Face Detection with JAVA

Tags: image, image-processing, face-detection

I am planning to develop a web app which will detect faces in a jpeg image. I will use tomcat for deployment. I want help on how to proceed.

I dont want any code.
Just a flowchart of steps will do. I want to avoid use of third party libraries for face detection. But please list all options.

Any information, algorithm, resource will be greatly helpful.
Thank you..

Comment: "I want to avoid use of third party libraries for face detection."

Comment: This questions has a lot of Java libraries for face detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a 3rd party lib such as OpenCV. You'll want to look at the Haar feature detector. There's some info here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection and plenty more on the OpenCV mailing list.

There are Java bindings for OpenCV http://code.google.com/p/javacv/ . But it might be easiest to produce a separate command line util that you shell out to in Tomcat.